# How to upload container wav file to encoder for converstion to mp4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, azure-storage, azure-media-services

I have been using samples from microsoft site for doing conversion from wav to mp4 with sample as given below.

IAsset singleWMVAsset = CreateAssetAndUploadSingleFile(AssetCreationOptions.None,
                   _singleInputWavPath);

```
        // EncodeToH264 creates a job with one task
        // that converts a mezzanine file (in this case interview1.wmv)
        // into an MP4 file (in this case, "H264 Broadband 720p").
        IAsset MP4Asset = CreateEncodingJob(singleWMVAsset, "H264 Broadband 720p");

        // BuildSasUrlForMP4File creates a SAS Locator
        // and builds the SAS Url that can be used to 
        // progressively download the MP4 file.
        string fullSASURL = BuildSasUrlForMP4File(MP4Asset);
```

However, here _singleInputWavPath expects file to be local path. So it works properly when we take path from local. However, my wav file are upload in azure container so i would like to make encoding work with stored container.

Is there any possibility of using asp .net mvc code to retrieve container and convert it to some compatible format and pass and create encoding job?

Will i need to look at creating cloud service and implement this mechanism?

Answer (score 0):

Please look into the code sample we provided here: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/How-to-Copy-an-Existing-5ccaac3e/view/SourceCode. This allows you to cope media asset from an existing azure storage account into the storage account attached to your media account.